# Tumblr theme javascript

Tags: javascript, themes, tumblr

I want to make my own tumblr theme. And I don't have any problems with html part, but I have a question about javascript part of the code.

I see all tumblr themes have links to static tumblr where they have Masonry, Modernizr and Infinite Scroll put together. Is that everything I need for my theme to work correctly?
Do I have to upload these libraries myself or I can use someone's else static tumblr link (I mean is there any common links to static tumblr I can use and people won't say I stole their code?)

Answer (score 4):

**Theme Assets**

All theme assets should be upload directly to Tumblr's CDN, using the static file uploader.

> Use this to host small files required for custom themes (images, css,
>   javascript). Once uploaded, files cannot be deleted or changed.

Link: https://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file

As for using other users links, whilst is possible, its not advised. AFAIK, the assets are stored against a users account. If the users account is removed, the assets may get removed as well.

Comment: Because if their account gets removed it might break your theme. And if there link doesn't do quite what you believe it to it could cause some unforeseen problems down the road.

Comment: Thank you, guys. So all I need is put Masonry and Infinite Scroll together and upload the file, right? Do I need to edit the Masonry or IS code to make them work with the html correctly? I just don't know javascript :(

Comment: @user3415893 Upload whatever scripts you need, then call / use them on your theme page. Both scripts have documents on how to get started.